# Cheapest Arduino wireless solution for home automation

Tags: arduino-uno, power, wifi, wireless

I am from programming background and newbie to this field.

Couple of days ago I brought **Arduino Uno (5V)**. I want to control light bulb and fan from my **Android**. So I thought, I will buy **relays** and **ESP8266** module and its done.

But now read somewhere that ESP8266 works with **3.3v** and my Arduino supplies **5v**.

Should I go for different Arduino board (like Arduino pro or Arduino mini) or is there any **reliable & cheap** solution that will work my **Arduino Uno (5V)** ?

Comment: Millions (well, hundreds or thousands) of people use the ESP8266 with the Arduino. There are trillions (well hundreds) of tutorials. Wiring it up requires two resistors. Is discovering that through google beyond your capabilities?

Comment: There are in fact around 300,000 hits on "ESP8266 Arduino" Google search. The top ones describe how to interface with a Uno, as this is a common problem. Did you check any of those before posting your question?

Comment: @Majenko I know there are 'There are trillions (well hundreds) of tutorials' and every article has something which contradict to the content of other. They left me more confuse thats why come to this forum, so if you don't want to help me its fine but keep your arrogant comment to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go for cheap just use a ESP8266 no arduino needed.

Comment: To elaborate this answer: Actually, you can download your own code to an ESP8266 module, as it comes with (a really powerful) microcontroller. Actually you can program it from Arduino IDE directly via an USB-serial cable. See https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/installing-the-esp8266-arduino-addon and http://makezine.com/2015/04/01/installing-building-arduino-sketch-5-microcontroller/ as a full example.